# How to make res_query work with dns caching?

Tags: c++, c, caching, dns, libresolv

I'm using libresolv to perform requests to dns servers.

Also i use local dns cache. (dnsmasq/unbound)

When i use `dig`, for example `dig google.com`, request gets cached and the next request uses cached value.

We can see this in dnsmasq logs:

```
Nov  9 10:46:46 y dnsmasq[24003]: query[A] google.com from 127.0.0.1
Nov  9 10:46:46 y dnsmasq[24003]: forwarded google.com to **.**.**.**
Nov  9 10:46:46 y dnsmasq[24003]: reply google.com is 173.194.32.165
Nov  9 10:46:46 y dnsmasq[24003]: reply google.com is 173.194.32.160
Nov  9 10:46:49 y dnsmasq[24003]: query[A] google.com from 127.0.0.1
Nov  9 10:46:49 y dnsmasq[24003]: cached google.com is 173.194.32.165
Nov  9 10:46:49 y dnsmasq[24003]: cached google.com is 173.194.32.168
```

Then i use `res_query`  and i get this:

```
Nov  9 10:50:29 y dnsmasq[24003]: query[MX] google.com from 127.0.0.1
Nov  9 10:50:29 y dnsmasq[24003]: forwarded google.com to **.**.**.**
Nov  9 10:50:29 y dnsmasq[24003]: forwarded google.com to **.**.**.**
Nov  9 10:51:13 y dnsmasq[24003]: query[MX] google.com from 127.0.0.1
Nov  9 10:51:13 y dnsmasq[24003]: forwarded google.com to **.**.**.**
Nov  9 10:51:13 y dnsmasq[24003]: forwarded google.com to **.**.**.**
```

So it looks like the response from dns server doesn't hit the dns cache and doesn't get cached.

Is there any way to cache request from `res_query` ?

This is how I'm making the request to the DNS resolver:

```
 struct __res_state dnsstate;
 int rc = res_ninit(&dnsstate);
 if (rc < 0) {
     return result;
 }
 dnsstate.retrans = timeout;

 int len = res_nquery(&dnsstate, domain.c_str(), ns_c_in, ns_t_mx, nsbuf, sizeof(nsbuf));
```

I suppose that res_nquery doesn't check local DNS cache, and dig does.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah so i should ask admins about how libresolv works? Stackoverflow became very ridiculous place to ask questions.

Comment: I may have misread the question (hard to tell now, I've got 9 hours of jetlag and only had 3 hours sleep) but as written I can't really tell what you're asking.  Try looking at tcpdump to see the difference (if any) between what libresolv is sending vs what dig is sending.  Perhaps also show some code to show _how_ you're using libresolv.

Comment: @Alnitak I've put some code in my question. Tnx for advice with tcpdump. I've already tried it. Seems like res_nquery still sends packets to check dns, while dig sends nothing, just checks dns cache.
Seems that res_nquery can only work with strait requests to dns

Comment: Both `dig` and `res_nquery` will just send the queries to whatever's in your `resolv.conf`, i.e. your dnsmasq instance, and both will also by default set the `+RD` bit to request recursion.   dnsmasq will then either serve the answers from cache, or go fetch if the TTL has expired, but there is to my knowledge _nothing in the DNS protocol itself_ (and therefore nothing in the `res_nquery` settings) that a client can set that will influence that behaviour.

Comment: p.s. also try sending the _same_ query - your `dig` example requests an A record but your `res_nquery` is asking for an MX record - perhaps dnsmasq itself behaves differently based on the query RTYPE ?

Comment: I've tried sending the same requests, both for an A record. The behavior doesn't change (however, dnsmasq really doesn't cache MX records. I switched to unbound that does, but that didn't help). In my `resolv.conf` localhost (127.0.0.1) is on the first place, so requests should go to local cache first, but seems they behave differently under the hood and i can't do anything with it.

@Alnitak can you put your comment about `dig` and `res_nquery` behavior as an aswer so that i can accept it? Thank you for explanation

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake I'd quite like to get to the bottom of this.  If you run `dig google.com A` and then (before the TTL expires) use your own code to make the same query it _should_ come from cache.

Comment: According to what i see from tcpdump `res_nquery` still sends one packet to remote servers (which means a new socket will be opened on the server side), but actual response comes from cache.

Comment: `res_nquery` won't (itself) send anything other than to the server in resolv.conf

Comment: Yes, but if i have localhost on first place and on the second - remote server, it still 'pings' to remote. Maybe i'm doing something wrong or misunderstood output of tcpdump, but it shows ip of remote server from resolv.conf.

Comment: You never mentioned before that you have _two_ servers in resolv.conf - your traces above only showed what dnsmasq was doing. It's perfectly possible that libresolv is trying them in a random order

Comment: @Alnitak Oh, okay. Thanks for your help! Good to know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both dig and `res_nquery()` will just send the queries to whatever's in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, i.e. your dnsmasq instance.  Both will also by default set the `RD` bit to request recursion.

dnsmasq will then either serve the answers from cache, or go fetch them if the TTL has expired.  However to my knowledge there is nothing in the DNS protocol itself (and therefore nothing in the `res_nquery` settings) that a client can set that will influence that behaviour